# Regex in Notepad++ to add something after first character

Tags: regex, notepad++

So I have example lines like these:

JJmartin

It needs to become:

J.Jmartin

I need regex to be able to insert . after first character in each line
i tried ^. and replace with . but that regex delete first character and replaces it with .
I also had an idea of maybe deleting everything after first character and then putting it together again with a program i have since i have a regex that deletes everything but the last character, so i tried to tweek it, but didn't work, that regex is:

```
.*([A-Za-z\d])  replace with         \1
```

Comment: Try `(?-i)^([A-Z])([A-Z][[:alpha:]]*)$` and replace with `$1.$2`. Do you mean you want to skip `JJmartin more text here` lines? If not, remove `$`, just try `(?-i)^([A-Z])([A-Z])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `^(.{1})` That is, from the beginning of each line, capture a single character.

Replace `\1\.` That is, the captured character with the same character followed by a dot. The dot should be escaped because of its meaning within regex.